# How to insert a tab to a Text in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want insert a tab to a text in react native before text. I tried in various ways but couldn't do it. Is there a way to do it by using a code like line break `\n`

```
<View> <Text>I want to shift this text right</Text> </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

The way i do it is using a javascript string inside the JSX Text component. This way you can write strings the "programming way".

```
<Text>{`\tI want to shift this text right`}</Text>
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit? And it appear as four space in you post. Did you intended to write a tab?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This works too...

```
<Text>{'    '}Hello world</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Text> {`\t I want to shift this text right`} </Text>
```

Comment: Add more detail to your answer so people can understand what this means, please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `&ensp;` or `&emsp;`

The `&ensp;` character entity is used to denote an `en` space which means half point size of the current font. This may be perceived as twice the space of a normal space.

The `&emsp;` character entity is used to denote an `em` space which means equal to the point size of the current font. This may be perceived as four times the space of a normal space.