# Word Spacing in React Native

Tags: react-native, word-spacing

We use letterSpacing for spacing between letters

> L    i   k    e      t    h    i    s

What if we want word spacing in react native?

> Like [space] this

Comment: This is workaroundish but may suffice for short text strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437834/how-to-insert-a-tab-to-a-text-in-react-native

Comment: but I think it's not proper way...there should be an specific property for like like CSS like word-spacing

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workaround. I have an inline `Text` element between the words that contains two zero-width non-breaking spaces and a `letterSpacing` property.

React Native treats those spaces as characters and renders the letter spacing between them, while the characters themselves don't contribute to the width of the spacing.

```js
<Text>
    Like
    <Text style={{letterSpacing: 16}}>&#xFEFF;&#xFEFF;</Text>
    this
</Text>
```