# adding a tab to a string in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an array which is dynamically filled with string data.
I would like to add tabs chars to the string to improve the interface layout of the component.
So I have a few conditions that check things before a value like `Temperature` is added.
After collecting the data I loop through the array to put it on the component in JSX format.

I would want to add tabs between `Temperature`, `value` and `score`.
I have tried combinations of `${Temperature: &#9;}` (enclosed in back-ticks "`", but I fail to get it to add tabs to the string.

```
let data =[];
data.push('Temperature: '+value+' - '+score);



{ass.includes("Temperature:") && <tr className={patOddEvenColor}>
    <td className={patOddEvenColor}>
        <div className='col-xs-12' >
            {ass}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do something like this with tabs? Why don't you use something like spans or divs and style them via CSS? This would be more flexible.
Also enhance your data structure, to make all of this flexible and dynamic.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437834/how-to-insert-a-tab-to-a-text-in-react-native/74704530#74704530

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace those spaces with `&nbsp;`

Comment: They're trying to use tabs, not nonbreaking spaces

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
let data = [];
let arrTemp = [];
.
.
.
arrTemp = [
    ['Temperature: '],
    [value],
    [score]
]
data.push('Temperature: ');
.
.
.
{ass.includes("Temperature:") && <tr className={patOddEvenColor}>
    <td className={patOddEvenColor}>
        <div className='col-xs-12' style={{padding: 0}}>
            <div className='col-xs-6'>
                {arrTemp[0]}
            </div>
            <div className='col-xs-3'>
                {arrTemp[1]}
            </div>
            <div className='col-xs-3'>
                {arrTemp[2]}
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>}
```